# How to iterate over Angular 2 ng-content items?

Tags: typescript, angular

Does anyone know how to iterate over Angular 2 ng-content items?

I need to check what are the values of the attributes difined on the items present inside ng-content. Does any one knows how to get them?

The best scenario is to get the actual component instances inside it, because I can have some inner properties set inside the components and accessing them directly would be great!

Some sample code:

```
// ====================== Container Component =======================

import * as ng from "angular2/angular2";

@ng.Component({
    selector: 'grid-layout',
    lifecycle: [ng.onInit]
})

@ng.View({
        templateUrl: `<div><ng-content></ng-content></div>`
})

export class GridLayout
{
    constructor(){

    }

    private onInit(): void {
         // ??? something like this.ngContent would be great :)
    }
}

// ====================== Caller Component =======================
import * as ng from "angular2/angular2";

@ng.Component({
    selector: 'my-page'
})

@ng.View({
    templateUrl: `
<grid-layout>
    <div data-att1="container 1">1</div>
    <div data-att2="container 2">2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</grid-layout>`,
    directives:[GridLayout]
})

export class MyPage
{
    constructor(){

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want to use @ViewQuery. The doc is not really helpful, so you would have to debug what it returns. I let you these threads [Support ViewQuery](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1935) and [@ViewQuery is the correct way to query the view template](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3033)

Comment: The second link should point to https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/3318, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Just inject the contents of light DOM using @ContentChildren

```
ParentComponent implements AfterContentInit{
  @ContentChildren(ChildComponent) contents : QueryList<ChildComponent>; 

  ngAfterContentInit()
  {
     //access contents here
  }

}
```

Comment: How do I know that the children are of `ChildComponent` type? Any way to get them without knowing type?

Comment: As long as children are ng2 components, they all can inherit from a common base component class.. 
if you want to know the native HTML elements (e.g. div/ h1 ..etc) in the content area (light DOM area), they can be injected using 

@ContentChildren(ElementRef) contents : QueryList<ElementRef>